# Передать значение в параметр

Tags: php, codeigniter, if

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно передать значение в параметр:

```
$star = $this->input->get('star');
```

Данный код получает число из таблицы и передает значение $star в код выше:

```
$this->db->join('q_rev', 'q_res.res_id = q_rev.rev_itemid', 'left');    
$this->db->select_avg('rev_overall', 'overall');
$this->db->where('overall', $star);
```

Мне нужно сделать условие, которое бы передавало значение в параметр $star. Если полученное значение таблицы от 0 до 2.4 (например 1.3), передаем 1. Если от 2.5 до 4.4, передаем 2.

Пробую условие ниже, не получается. Берет данные все равно из $this->db->where('overall', $star);, исключая условие if.

```
if($star > '0' && $star < '2.4'){
     // передать $star что это 1
}

if($star > '2.5' && $star < '4.4'){
     // передать $star что это 2
}
```

Как можно реализовать? Может условие другое составить? Спасибо.

Comment: зачем вам переопределять одну и туже переменную. Не совсем понятна задача, я бы подумал что вы просто хотите подставить в нужное место `$star = 1;`

Comment: мне нужно сделать условие, что если получили от 0 до 2.4, выдать 1. и т.д. $star = 1; пробовал, но читает все равно из запроса $this->db->where('overall', $star); игнорируя условия if

Comment: так вы уже написали в принципе. или я просто не так понимаю вас

Comment: приведите более полный код тогда

Comment: попробовал подробно описать суть и добавил остальное код.